# encodeToString base64 android issue

Tags: android, string, base64

i want to encode string to binary64 however i found an error and i dont know how to solve this. this is my code that im using.

```
String text = name1.getText().toString();
    // Sending side
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

however, `Base64.encodeToString` showing error saying require API level 8(current min sdk is 1). but im using android 2.2 and i believe its min sdk is 8. am i right?

than i tried to review the issue and it appear to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Why not just set the min API level to 8? Setting the min API level to 1 is useless--there are no devices that run anything below level 3. According to [the dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), all devices below level 8 represent less than 4 percent of the market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your manifest file, there will be an entry in there like

```
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Make sure it's at least 8 It sounds like it's set to 1